# Listar duas tabelas mysql pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
$catalog = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM catalogo WHERE ativo = 2 ORDER BY catalogo_view DESC LIMIT 0,5");
$catalog->execute();
```

Quero buscar entre duas tabelas, como faço?

Comment: JOIN? existe correspondencia entre as tabelas?

Comment: As duas tabelas estão interligadas?

Comment: Se as tabelas tiverem uma referencia em comum, pode usar o join.
`Select * from tabela1 join tabela 2
on tabela1.campo = tabela2.campo`

Answer (score -1):

Tente usar UNION, mas lembrando que no UNION as colunas da consulta tem que ter a mesma quantidade.

```
SELECT cliente_codigo, cliente_nome FROM cliente
UNION SELECT funcionario_codigo, funcionario_nome FROM funcionario
WHERE ativo = 2
```